# Histogram Binning of Gradient Vectors

Tags: c++, image-processing, graphics, statistics, computer-vision

I am working on a project that has a small component requiring the comparison of distributions over image gradients. Assume I have computed the image gradients in the x and y directions using a Sobel filter and have for each pixel a 2-vector. Obviously getting the magnitude and direction is reasonably trivial and is as follows:

[image: Magnitude and Direction Equations]

However, what is not clear to me is how to bin these two components in to a two dimensional histogram for an arbitrary number of bins.

I had considered something along these lines(written in browser):

```
//Assuming normalised magnitudes.
//Histogram dimensions are bins * bins.
int getHistIdx(float mag, float dir, int bins) {
    const int magInt = reinterpret_cast<int>(mag);
    const int dirInt = reinterpret_cast<int>(dir);
    const int magMod = reinterpret_cast<int>(static_cast<float>(1.0));
    const int dirMod = reinterpret_cast<int>(static_cast<float>(TWO_PI));

    const int idxMag = (magInt % magMod) & bins
    const int idxDir = (dirInt % dirMod) & bins;
    return idxMag * bins + idxDir;
}
```

However, I suspect that the mod operation will introduce a lot of incorrect overlap, i.e. completely different gradients getting placed in to the same bin.

Any insight in to this problem would be very much appreciated.

I would like to avoid using any off the shelf libraries as I want to keep this project as dependency light as possible. Also I intend to implement this in CUDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a what is an histogram question? rather than one of your tags. Two things:

1. In a 2D plain two directions equal by modulation of 2pi are in fact the same - so it makes sense to modulate.
2. I see no practical or logical reason of modulating the norms.

Next, you say you want a "two dimensional histogram", but return a single number. **A 2D histogram, and what would make sense in your context, is a 3D plot** - the plane is theta/R, 2 indexed, while the 3D axis is the "count".

So first suggestion, return

```
return Pair<int,int>(idxMag,idxDir);
```

Then you can make a 2D histogram, or 2 2D histograms.

**Regarding the "number of bins"**

this is use case dependent. **You** need to **define** the number of bins you want (maybe different for theta and R). Maybe just some constant 10 bins? Maybe it should depend on the amount of vectors? In any case, you need a function that receives either the number of vectors, or the total set of vectors, and returns the number of bins for each axis. This could be a constant (10 bins) initially, and you can play with it. Once you decide on the number of bins:

**Determine the bins**

1. For a bounded case such as `0<theta<2 pi`, this is easy. Divide the interval equally into the number of bins, assuming a flat distribution. Your modulation actually handles this well - if you would have actually modulated by 2*pi, which you didn't. You would still need to determine the bin bounds though.
2. For `R` this gets trickier, as this is unbounded. Two options here, but both rely on the same tactic - choose a maximal bin. Either arbitrarily (Say `R=10`), so any vector longer than that is placed in the "longer than max" bin. The rest is divided equally (for example, though you could choose other distributions). Another option is for the longest vector to determine the edge of the maximal bin.

**Getting the index**

Once you have the bins, you need to search the magnitude/direction of the current vector in your bins. If bins are pairs representing min/max of bin (and maybe an index), say in a linked list, then it would be something like (for mag for example):

```
bin = histogram.first;
while ( mag > bin.min ) bin = bin.next;
magIdx = bin.index;
```

If the bin does not hold the index you can just use a counter and increase it in the while. Also, for the magnitude the final bin should hold "infinity" or some large number as a limit.  Note this has nothing to do with modulation, though that would work for your direction - as you have coded. I don't see how this makes sense for the norm.

Bottom line though, you have to think a bit about what you want. In any case all the "objects" here are trivial enough to write yourself, or  even use small arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should arrange your bins in a square array, and then bin by vx and vy independently.

If your gradients are *reasonably* even you just need to scan the data first to accumulate the min and max in x and y, and then split the gradients evenly.

If the gradients are very unevenly distributed, you might want to sort the (eg) vx first and arrange that the boundaries between each bin exactly evenly divides the values.

An intermediate solution might be to obtain the min and max ignoring the (eg) 10% most extreme values.